# how to make it drag with 2 fingers?

Tags: java, android

I am able to pinch zoom in/out (though its not perfect yet) i want to use 2 fingers to drag since single drag is for drawing.

is this where the `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` is required?

please help me how i can have the paint app drag with 2 fingers?

Below is the code

Thank you!

```
public class paintView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

private final ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

Paint paint;
Path path;

public paintView(Context context) {
    super(context, null, 0);

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    paint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            path.moveTo(x,y);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            float x = ev.getX();
            float y = ev.getY();

            path.lineTo(x,y);
            break;

        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }


    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // for moving around
    // 2 finger drag 할때 필요할듯
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    // for zoom
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    //mImage.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    //canvas.restore();
}

// zoom in gesture
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        final float scale = detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor * scale, 3.0f));

        if (mScaleFactor < 5f) {
            // 1 Grabbing
            final float centerX = detector.getFocusX();
            final float centerY = detector.getFocusY();
            // 2 Calculating difference
            float diffX = centerX - mPosX;
            float diffY = centerY - mPosY;
            // 3 Scaling difference
            diffX = diffX * scale - diffX;
            diffY = diffY * scale - diffY;
            // 4 Updating image origin
            mPosX -= diffX;
            mPosY -= diffY;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

}
```